# Casimir of $SO(3)$, $SO(2)$, $IO(1,3)$, $T(4)$

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, poincare-symmetry, invariants

It is known that $SO(3)$, a semisimple group of rank 1, has one Casimir $J^2$, and one can use this information to classify its irreps with the eigenvalues of $J^2$ and $J_3$: $(j,m)$. Now, only $j$ is an eigenvalue of a Casimir, and therefore the different irreps are characterized by different values of $j$, while different values of $m$ simply span the elements of the $j$ representation.

$SO(3)$ has a subgroup, $SO(2)$, and its irreps are characterized by different values of $m$, the eigenvalue of its only generator $J$. **Can one say that $J$ is a Casimir of $SO(2)$?**

---

I also learned that the *not semisimple* Poincaré group $IO(1,3)$ has two Casimirs, $P^2$ and $W^2$ (where [W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli%E2%80%93Lubanski_pseudovector) is the Pauli-Lubanski pseudovector) and therefore one can characterize the irreps with eigenvalues of $P^2, P, W^2, W$: $(m,p,s,\sigma)$ but again only $m$ and $s$ are eigenvalues of Casimirs so they characterize different irreps. **Do I have a way of knowing how many Casimirs this group will have since it's not semisimple?**

Analogously, $IO(1,3)$ has an *invariant* subgroup, $T(4)$, and its irreps are characterized by different values of $p$, the eigenvalue of $P$. **Can one say that $P$ is a Casimir of $T(4)$?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, central elements of the Lie algebra are not called Casimir elements, normally involving higher powers of generators, but, hey!, for SO(2), nobody will stop you from calling its sole generator, commuting with itself, a Casimir, but it would sound puzzling in its triviality; its eigenvalues certainly quantify the charge of the 1-dim reps.

For ISO(1,3), well, look at its [uncontracted parent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_contraction)  SO(1,4) which has two Casimirs. Unless one modified  a Lie algebra with [central extensions, e.g.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation#Central_extension_of_the_Galilean_group), the number of Casimirs should stay the same in  such contractions.

As for T(4), it is abelian, so, yet again, each of  its 4 generators characterizes a T(4) irrep, kind of trivially.